# Armadillo: matrix.i(true) vs matrix.i()—one is a logic error, the other isn't?

Tags: c++, armadillo

The input matrix looks like this:

```
[ 1 2 4 ]
[ 4 5 6 ]
[ 7 8 9 ]
```

(mat1)

[Wolfram Alpha confirms it has an inverse.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B7%2C+8%2C+9%5D%5D+inverse) Using `matrix.i()` (which means it uses the fast invert) yields the approximately correct result of

```
[  1.0000 -4.6667  2.6667 ]
[ -1.0000  6.3333 -3.3333 ]
[  1.0000 -2.0000  1.0000 ]
```

(mat2)

But turning slow mode on by writing `matrix.i(true)` causes it to throw a `logic_error`. **Any reason that would do that?**

The reason I tried to turn it on is that the multiplying the inverted matrix by a vector of

```
[ 15 ]
[ 24 ]
[ 35 ]
```

(mat3)

yields an incorrect answer of

```
[ -3.6667 ]
[ 20.3333 ]
[  2.0000 ]
```

(mat4)

[when it should be this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28inverse+of+%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B7%2C+8%2C+9%5D%5D%29+%2a+%5B%5B15%2C+24%2C+35%5D%5D), or

```
[ -3.6667 ]
[  5.3333 ]
[  2.0000 ]
```

(mat5)

Checking immediately before the multiplication confirmed that the input *(mat3)* was correct, leading me to believe that the fast inverse created an incorrect matrix as an output *(mat4 instead of mat5)*.

... Now that I think of it, the fast inverse is correct and there is no reason for it to not be correct... This is a quandary.

The main question is, as written above,

**Any reason `matrix.i(true)` causes a logic error while `matrix.i()` doesn't?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour on my system. Are you sure you didn't accidentally change matrix dimensions as well when you added the `true` for slow mode?

Comment: @us2012 I literally juat wrote 'true' in the parentheses. Hmm. :/

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem either. On my system Armadillo is giving exactly the same results as Wolfram Alpha. What's the exact code that you're using?  Also, what OS and system are you using?

Comment: No idea about the cause, but your inverse (mat2) is not "approximately correct", the first column ought to be `1, -2, 1`. `mat4` is the correct product of `mat2 * mat3`.